# How to enlarge this text vertical area and subtract its horizontal area?

Tags: html, css, text, area

So say I have this: [image]

I want to make the blue/purple text's horizontally smaller and vertically bigger. Help? Some code might help:

```css
.n {
  color: #7986cb;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  top: -10px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: oblique;
}
.n:hover {
  color: #3f51b5;
}
.mc {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  outline-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section class="mc">
  <a class="n">O sociólogo francês Emile Durkheim estuda a sociedade como um organismo. É preciso que tomemos cuidado com todos órgãos de nossa sociedade, façamos com que eles trabalhem em conjunto, pois, se um deles possui dificuldades, isso virá a afetar todo o funcionamento da mesma. Pequenos atos serão os primeiros passos para manter nosso organismo saudável e nutrido.</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the dimensions of mc so that as the user changes the size of the screen, the container will resize, or do you want the text itself (font, etc) to resize?

Comment: I want it's text (O sociólogo francês...) to have the same formation as it would have if mc's position was absolute. @AndrewFan

Comment: Like this: https://gyazo.com/19239a7d773fc2773f9dae0907fbd6df @AndrewFan

Comment: Just change the max-width of the section to any percentage smaller than 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by changing the `width` on the section :

```
.mc {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  outline-width: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17bj86k9/2/)